# Spring LdapTemplate org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder problem

Tags: spring, ldap, slf4j

I would like to create LdapTemplate:

```
        LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
        contextSource.setUrl(ldapUrl);
        contextSource.setUserDn(ldapPrincipal);
        contextSource.setPassword(ldapPassword);
        contextSource.setAuthenticationSource(new BasicAuthenticationSource(ldapPrincipal, ldapPassword));
        contextSource.setReferral(LDAP_REFFERAL);
        contextSource.setCacheEnvironmentProperties(false);
        this.ldapTemplate = new LdapTemplate(contextSource);
        ldapTemplate.setDefaultCountLimit(LDAP_RESULTS_LIMIT);
        ldapTemplate.setDefaultSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
        ldapTemplate.setDefaultTimeLimit(LDAP_TIME_LIMIT);
```

I have LdapTemplate dependency in pom:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

The problem is that during `LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource()`
invocation there is slsf4j problem:

```
  SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".|#]  SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation|#]   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.|#]
```

I see that slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar is on depenedencies list

Comment: Do you also have logback on your dependency list?

Comment: Well, I added
<dependency>
<groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
<artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
<version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
and it is ok now. Is this dependency good enough, logback classic?